# VirtualBox VM no unallocated space shown in Gparted

Tags: virtualbox, partition

I resized a .vdi file to a new size, which registers correctly in VirtualBox. Now I want to resize the partition through GParted, but GParted doesn't show any unallocated space. How can I get GParted to recognize the new space?

Answer (score 12):

Ok, I solved it. I figured out that I needed to delete all Snapshots. But this wouldnt work for some reasons. So I made a clone with not Snapshots and then I could use Gparted in a proper way.

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing your solution! I was stuck with the same problem.